# Figure out which DLLs the application references?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am taking over an application that was built by a third-party software company. There is an executable that is currently not working because it is missing a DLL that is referenced. How can I figure out which DLLs the application references?

Comment: Do you know whether you are talking about managed DLLs or native DLLs as dependencies?

Comment: @SteveMitcham, I don't know. The question is from a book. It doesn't mention it.

Comment: It depends, could be an unmanaged DLL, could be an assembly loaded explicitly.  You cover all possibilities by using SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Towards the end of the trace, you'll see the test app searching for the DLL and not finding it.  If you don't want to use tools then use a telephone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

for example:

```
var targetAsm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("[TargetPath]"));
foreach(var an in targetAsm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    Console.WriteLine(an.ToString());   
}
```

Comment: What are the steps? **Create an instance of the Assembly class, load the assembly, and call the GetReferencedAssemblies method?**

Answer (score 0):

For managed assemblies, you can load the application and assemblies that you do have into a decompiler like [dotPeek from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). You can also you `ildasm.exe` that is delivered with the .NET SDK. This will give you a list of managed references.

For unmanaged DLLs, you'll need to search the code for P/Invoke calls by finding the `[DllImport]` attribute in your code.  These should have the names of the imported DLLs that you are looking for.

Once you have a set of native DLLs, using something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) will give you the remaining unmanaged DLLs you need.

Comment: I don't want to use other tools. Suppose it is for managed assemblies, how can I use reflection code to figure it out?

Comment: This is what I do in my job every day.  As a maintainer, I wouldn't write code to do this, I'd use existing tooling.  However, http://shazwazza.com/post/how-to-inspect-assemblies-before-including-them-in-your-application-with-reflection/ is an article describing what you are trying to do in code.